# Method and inner class with the same name (error: ... conflicts with a previous declaration)

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I intend to have a class which has an inner class and a method with similar names. The code of `example1.cpp` compiles with no problem even though I have the an inner class and a method with the same name `B`. While `example2.cpp` will not work if I rename `Position` to `position` with small letters. In such a case, the `position()` method and the `position` class conflict with each other and I receive:

```
error: ‘ObjType::position<false> ObjType::position() const’ conflicts with a previous declaration
  inline auto position() const->class position<false>{return {*this};}
                                                                     ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

What is the difference between these two classes? Why the latter one is giving error but not the former one?

```
g++ -std=c++11 exampleX.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors && ./a.out
```

.

```
// example1.cpp

#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    friend class B;

    class B
    {
    public:
        int x;
        void show() {std::cout<<"x: "<<x<<std::endl;}
        B(): x(6) {}
    };

    B B()
    {
        class B b;
        return b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.B().show();
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
// example2.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Point
{
public:
    double x,y,z;
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout<<"x:"<<x<<", y:"<<y<<", z:"<<z<<std::endl;
    }
};

class ObjType
{
    template<bool> friend class Position;

    Point data;
public:
    template<bool ByRef>
    class Position
    {
        typename std::conditional<ByRef,ObjType&,ObjType const&>::type ref;
    public:
        inline Position(typename std::conditional<ByRef, ObjType&, ObjType const&>::type ref) : ref(ref) {}
        inline Position(const Point &ref): ref(ref){}
        inline auto operator =(Point const& a)->Position&{ref.data.subvec(0,2)=a; return *this;}
        inline auto operator =(Point&& a)->Position&{data=a; return *this;}
        inline void print() const{ref.data.print();}
    };

    inline ObjType(const Point &data): data(data){}
    inline void print() const{data.print();}
    /*error > */ inline auto position() const->class Position<false>{return {*this};}
    inline auto position()->class Position<true>{return {*this};}
};

int main()
{
    ObjType obj({1.1,1.2,1.3});
    std::cout<<"****************"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"obj.print() :"<<std::endl;
    obj.print();
    std::cout<<"obj.position.print() :"<<std::endl;
    obj.position().print();
    std::cout<<"****************"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that for c++, position an Position are just 2 different identifiers, like dog and cat. Avoid to use identifiers different only for capitalization. Compiler will not get confused, but programmer (including you) probably will

Comment: @GianPaolo, I am planning to create an automatic code generator. And due to the lack of the terminologies, I even prefer to have a function and a class name similar. However, I am a fan of the clean code.

Comment: you (or someone else) will have to work with the automatic generated code; a difference in case for an identifier will not be easily spotted. Consider prependig an underscore _ or something else instead

Comment: @GianPaolo, the problem is when a user uses both `position` and `_position`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two classes? Why the latter one is giving error but not the former one?

We can further reduce your example to the following class:

```
struct S {
    struct C {};
    void C() {}
};
```

In this case, the standard [doesn't forbid](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#name-2) the introduction of a class the name of which is already in use. It's definitely opened to such a case indeed:

> If a class name is declared in a scope where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then [...]

It just rules on how it can be referred and what hides what.
On the other side, consider the following class:

```
struct S {
    template<typename> struct C {};
    void C() {}
};
```

In this case the standard [strictly forbids it](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#7) (with a few exceptions, none of which applies here):

> A class template shall not have the same name as any other template, class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type in the same scope

Therefore there is no chance you can name your class template and the other function around with the same identifier.
You can still pack all of your types within an enclosing scope where you don't define functions with the same name anyway. As an example:

```
struct S {
    struct T {
        template<typename>
        struct C {};
    };

    void C() {}
};
```

Then access them as:

```
S::T::C<void> c;
```

Comment: Excellent! :) This one is deserving to be the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @Arafangion Thank you. Anyway, you shouldn't delete your answers. The fact that an answer isn't accepted doesn't mean that it must be wiped out.

Comment: Your answer included everything mine had, and did it better, I saw no value in keeping it! :)  Do you want me to put it back?

Comment: @Arafangion I think any meaningful answer should survive, even if it's not tagged as accepted. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your example1 and example2 differ in one significant way: example1 does not involve template classes, here is a version of example1 that also fails:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    template<bool> friend class B;
public:
    template<bool ByRef>
    class B
    {
    public:
        int x;
        void show() {std::cout<<"x: "<<x<<std::endl;}
        B(): x(6) {}
    };

    B<true> B()
    {
        class B<true> b;
        return b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.B().show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the solution for example2? I can I have an inner class+template and a method with the same name?

Comment: I don't know, but I would be inclined to suggest that you shouldn't. It's confusing, so don't do that.

(Don't accept this as an answer, the answer should involve the technical reason why it fails)